# Adding custom headers in .NET WebAPI 2 hosted by IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I wrote a WEBAPI application with C# that works fine while developing but when in production, hosted by IIS 8.5 I got a problem.

In order to enable CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) in my controller, I implemented the OPTION action:

```
[HttpOptions]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage();

    res.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "User-Agent, Content-Type, Accept, X-ApplicationId, Authorization, Host, Content-Length");
    res.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    res.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return res;
}
```

As I wrote before everything works ok on Visual Studio but in production, when I make an OPTIONS request using Fiddler, the answer is always:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 16:56:20 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

I know that is possible to add Header's key statically in IIS but, in my controller, I need to add a Custome Header with dynamic values like that:

```
res.Headers.Add("X-App-Limit-Remaining", getRemainingCalls());
```

Anybody knows how to overwrite/change HTTP headers from a C# WEB API hosted by IIS 8. ?

Many Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1):

You can tap into the request pipeline by using a `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`

Reference: [HTTP Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

> You can add custom handlers to the pipeline. Message handlers are good
>   for cross-cutting concerns that operate at the level of HTTP messages
>   (rather than controller actions). For example, a message handler
>   might:
>
> - Read or modify request headers.
> - **Add a response header to responses.**
> - Validate requests before they reach the controller.

Using your rate limit example here is a simplified handler:

```
public class WebApiRateLimitHandler : DelegatingHandler {

    //Override the SendAsync Method to tap into request pipeline
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response.ContinueWith(task => {
            var httpResponse = task.Result;
            httpResponse.Headers.Add("X-App-Limit-Remaining", getRemainingCalls());
            return httpResponse;
        });        
    }
}
```

### Adding a Handler to the Pipeline

> Message handlers are called in the same order that they appear in
>   MessageHandlers collection. Because they are nested, the response
>   message travels in the other direction. That is, the last handler is
>   the first to get the response message.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        //Order handlers are added is important. First in last out
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WebApiRateLimitHandler());
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SomeOtherMessageHandler());

        // Other code not shown...
    }
}
```

There is also an **X-HTTP-Method-Override** example. Checkout the referenced link for more examples.